# Append multiple lines through TextBlock Text Binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, textblock

So I created a TextBlock that I want to log all my messages to but at the moment I am stuck where I only post 1 message at a time and overwrite the previous message. My current code:

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="LogTextBlock" Foreground="Silver"
           Height="480" Width="588" Margin="10,10,0,0"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
       <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}">
                 <Binding Path="LogText" />
            </MultiBinding>
       </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>
```

Code:

```
    public class StatusLogger : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static string _logText;

        public string LogText
        {
            get { return _logText; }
            set
            {
                if (_logText == value) return;

                _logText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LogText");
            }
        }

        public static void WriteLine(string text, params object[] args)
        {
            _logText = String.Format(text, args);
        }

        #region Property Change Handler

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And how I am using the StatusLogger is using it statically throughout my code, e.g.

```
StatusLogger.WriteLine("{0}: Testing the first message!{1}", DateTime.Now, Environment.NewLine);
StatusLogger.WriteLine("{0}: Testing the second message!{1}", DateTime.Now, Environment.NewLine);
```

Basically, it's showing one line at a time, but I want it to show a history of every line I add to it. I've tried it a couple different ways but I currently posted what I have at the moment.

Comment: Why not have a static `StringBuilder` and `AppendLine` log messages to it. Then bind to the `ToString()`

Comment: @Jim "wrongest" comment ever. You cannot bind to a method.

Comment: @HighCore Did I ever imply you could? It should be obvious I was taking a high level approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `WriteLine()` method overwrites anything in `_logText` with the return value of `String.Format()`. So effectively you're replacing the line logged previously with the new line.

A better approach might be to use a `StringBuilder`, especially if you anticipate having a lot of lines shown:

```
public class StatusLogger : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static StringBuilder _logText = new StringBuilder();

    public string LogText
    {
        get { return _logText.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            _logText = new StringBuilder(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("LogText");
        }
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string text, params object[] args)
    {
        _logText.AppendFormat(text + Environment.NewLine, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, only thing I was trying to avoid was creating a new StringBuilder every time I added a message. That's why I was trying to store the values in the TextBlock.Text property (then append a new message). - Anyway, this is an answer to my problem, thank you Andy!

Comment: @HuntK24 You can also use `_logText.Clear()` to remove all text instead of creating a new object

Comment: I think using '+ Environment.NewLine' here defeats the purpose of using a StringBuilder. This code will set the GC on fire. Also if we are not using the dependency property itself to append lines how is the binding going to recognize the change.